# Synchronisation between office365 and local Active Directory via Custom field

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, entra-id, office365

I'm trying co connect local `Active Directory` to `office365` for usersync.

In [this documentation](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2832587&seqNum=3) i have found that i need make resolvable suffix in `userPrincipalName` and move legacy `Kerberos` principal to combination of `sAMAccoutName`+`@Realm`
The problem is that many of kerberized software has used [older documentation from Microsoft](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/03/06/kerberos-for-the-busy-admin/) for usage of `userPrincipalName`.

So some Services and Sevice Users have symbols in `userPrincipalName` that are not supported in `sAMAccoutName`
For example by hadoop services:

```
userPrincipalName=hive/host@COMPANY.REALM
```

And `sAMAccountName` looks like:

```
sAMAccountName=$XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

If I enable legacy `Kerberos` principal my tickets are not working for services with unsupported symbols.
Example:

```
[hive@host ~]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1234
Default principal: $XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX@COMPANY.REALM
```

Is it possible to create in `Active Directory` field like `userPrincipalNameForOffice365` for user synchronization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use other fields - but you have to add them manually in your synchronization job. The ADSync assistant will only allow certain fields (like SMTPProxyAdress).

More about alternate IDs: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-userprincipalname

You could even use AFDS to let AzureAD authenticate directly against your local domain (using alternate IDs): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configuring-alternate-login-id

Hope this helps. The whole answer would be hard to cover in one SF post.